# Should you to shut down an Azure VM to back up?

Tags: azure, backup, virtual-machine

We've got 2x Virtual Machines on Azure running within a single cloud service on a load balanced set.

I want to schedule periodic back ups of the VM images in blob storage; so taking the active VHDs and copying them into a separate backup container.

The question is; can I safely do that whilst the VMs are online, or should I only do this when the VMs are shut down?  If we restore from a backup taken when the VMs were online, will there be an issue using the image for a new VM?

Comment: How are you backing up? Just a file copy of the VHD?

Comment: That's right; direct copy of the VHD in blob storage - container to container.  We have backups inside the VM itself, this is more to ensure we have a current back up of the whole image.

Comment: Normally, you'd use VSS for that to get a consistent snapshot, but I don't think anything similar is supported for Azure virtual machines (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now backup Azure IaaS VMs while they are running. You can find more information about that feature here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-first-look-arm/

Comment: That's great thank you Jennelle!  Having looked at it the recovery vault looks like a better way to manage backups than manual VHD copying as well